# How to decode html to char in c#

Tags: c#

Im a newbie here.I need help how to decode a html string "&#128081" to char in c#? it should be show crown character or if its not supported it should show a rectangle.Im working for iOS.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: What do you mean, "working for iOS"?

Comment: @mason ...all your base are belong to us.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to Decode HTML to Unicode Chars

```
string s =  System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#128081");
```